# AlertDialog a partir de outra classe

Tags: java, android

O meu problema é o seguinte, eu tenho uma *Activity* que chama métodos de uma classe Java comum para realização de operações.

Agora me surgiu a necessidade de um desses métodos ser um `AlertDialog`, já pesquisei em vários lugares e não encontro solução, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor esse problema? Quem sabe algum código? Não percebi qual o teu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie um método nessa sua classe separada, com os seguintes parâmetros:

```
public static void showAlert(Context context, String title, String message){

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create(); 
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
        alertDialog.show();

}
```

Ai pra chama-lo, faça o seguinte:

```
SuaClasseOndeEstaoMetodo.showAlert(this, "Erro", "A imagem não pode ser carregada");
```

Answer (score 3):

Crie uma classe:

```
public class Message {

    public static void Alert(Context context, String Mensagem) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        //ADICIONANDO UM TITULO A NOSSA MENSAGEM DE ALERTA
        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name); //ou alertDialog.setTitle("Nome do app");

        //MENSAGEM A SER EXIBIDA
        alertDialog.setMessage(Mensagem);

        //CRIA UM BOTÃO COM O TEXTO OK SEM AÇÃO
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

        //MOSTRA A MENSAGEM NA TELA
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

E para "chamar" o Alerta use:

```
Message.Alert(this, this.getString(R.string.save)); 
//ou Message.Alert(this, "Mensagem Desejada");
```

Obs: Se usar *strings*, em *values\strings.xml* adicione:

```
<string name="save">Salvo com Sucesso!</string>
<string name="app_name">Nome do App</string>
```